# Joint probability density function of $X$ and $\frac{Y}{X}$

Tags: probability, density-function, exponential-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be exponential distributed. (Independent)

Find the joint pdf of $X$ and $\frac{Y}{X}$ . And find the pdf of $\frac{Y}{X}$.

Idea: 
I think that we can compute the cumulative probability function.

$ F(a,b) = P( X \le a, \frac{Y}{X} \le b) = P( X\le a, Y \le bX) =\int_0^a f(x) ( \int_0^{bx} g(y) dy) dx  = \int_0^a f(x) ( 1- e^{-\lambda b x} ) dx $ but what can I do now?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You mean... how do you complete the integration or what you do after that?

Comment: You know the density of $X$, too... another exponential (same or different $\lambda$, whatever).

Comment: Exactly. You are right.  I can replace f(x).  Unfortunately I'm not able to complete the integration.

Comment: Why not? Expand it out and you just have exponentials...

Answer (score 1):

Let's see... (I'll call $Z=\tfrac YX$)
$$F_{XZ}(a,b)=\int_0^a \int_0^{bx} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \mu e^{-\mu y} \, dy\, dx=\int_0^a \lambda e^{-\lambda x}(1-e^{-\mu b x}) \, dx=$$
$$= \lambda \int_0^a e^{-\lambda x}-e^{-(\lambda +\mu b) x}) \, dx=\lambda \left. \left(\frac{e^{-(\lambda+\mu b)x}}{\lambda+\mu b}-\frac{e^{-\lambda x}}{\lambda}\right)\right|_0^a=$$
$$=1-\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu b}-e^{-\lambda a}+\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu b}e^{-(\lambda + \mu b)a}.$$

So the joint CDF, lets call it $F_{XZ}(x,z)$ is
$$F_{XZ}(x,z)=1-\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu z}-e^{-\lambda x}+\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu z}e^{-(\lambda + \mu z)x},\qquad x,z\ge 0,$$
and zero in other case.

Then you can find a joint density of $X$ and $Z$ taking partial derivatives, once with respect to each variable, that is
$$f_{XZ}(x,z)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z \partial x}F_{XZ}(x,z)$$
(and in those specific points where derivatives don't exist—like the axes in this example—you can put whatever you want).

---

To find the PDF of $Z$ you can, as usual, integrate in $x$, that is
$$f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{XZ}(x,z) \, dx.$$

Nevertheless, the path you chose gives an even better (I mean, more straightforward) option: first calculate the CDF of $Z$, then derive (in its only variable) to find its PDF. This is easier as only involves taking a limit:
$$F_Z(z)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}F_{XZ}(x,z)$$
So for $z\ge0$
$$F_Z(z)=\lim_{x\to+\infty} \left(1-\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu z}-e^{-\lambda x}+\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu z}e^{-(\lambda + \mu z)x}\right)=1-\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu z}$$
(since both exponentials tend to $0$),
and $F_Z(z)=0$ if $z<0$.

And so
$$f_Z(z)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\lambda\mu}{(\lambda+\mu z)^2} & z\ge 0\\
0& z<0. \\
\end{cases}$$